# Create permission screen like PlayStore

Tags: android, android-permissions

I wanna create permission screen like playstore permission screen. I get permission string from apk AndroidManifest but I wanna show category in which permission it fall and description of the permission. Could someone help me how can I get the category and description for each `<uses-permission`> in manifest

Please refer below image

[image]

Comment: have you checked the documentation? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html

Comment: @Yazan I checked that documentation I got description but there is no documentation on categories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can get `PermissionInfo` from `packageManager` and by `permissionInfo` I can get label and label of `permissionGroup`

```
PermissionInfo permissionInfo = getPackageManager().getPermissionInfo("android.permission.WAKE_LOCK", 0);
PermissionGroupInfo groupInfo = pM.getPermissionGroupInfo(permissionInfo.group, 0);
```